# Updating my GitHub repository from using 'git push' in Mac terminal doesnt work

Tags: git, github

anyone ever experienced dealing with this type of issue? When I finished updating my python code, I did the 'git push' to update my repository on GitHub. I checked my repository manually on GitHub to see if updated. However it didnt update. That's why I wasnt able to deploy code correctly for my live server after testing my staging-server - I still received two '.has-error' statements: (I am doing TDD book - chapter 17: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_deploying_validation.html)

Your help/feedback would be so much appreciated!

Comment: Start by typing ```git status```. What shows up? Are you connected to your repo?

Comment: Are you first adding: ```git add -a```, then committing ```git commit -am "message"```?

Comment: I got this issue resolved by fixing the following commands:                                                                          ```git add .
and then

git commit -m "updates done by..."
and then

git push origin <repo_name>```                                      Thank you all!